# check / uncheck checkboxes the easy way

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to be able to check 2 checkboxes, 1 "status box" and 1 "status-update box" And I've tried the convenient way of doing this,

using for example this code:

```
   $("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
      var $box = $(this);
      if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $box.prop("checked", true);
      } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
      }
    });
```

But this only worked in my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb7oyzaf/6/), not in my application, I'm not sure if it's because I'm using a modal-dialog or not, but it's not working - unknown reason

So I figured I'd do it the rookie way, like this:

```
      if ($('.checkboxSanction').prop('checked')) {
            $('.checkboxPep').prop('checked', false);
            $('.checkboxUnderage').prop('checked', false);
        }
        if ($('.checkboxPep').prop('checked')) {
            $('.checkboxSanction').prop('checked', false);
            $('.checkboxUnderage').prop('checked', false);
        }
        if ($('.checkboxUnderage').prop('checked')) {
            $('.checkboxSanction').prop('checked', false);
            $('.checkboxPep').prop('checked', false);
        }
        if ($('.checkboxInvestigating').prop('checked')) {
            $('.checkboxClosed').prop('checked', false);
        }
        if ($('.checkboxClosed').prop('checked')) {
            ('.checkboxInvestigating').prop('checked', false);
        }
});
```

But here I have to uncheck 1 checkbox before being able to re-check one of the "checked, false" ones.

Do you guys have any ideas of how to do this in a rookie way that's bullet proof? - maybe not the best way but it works, if you know what I mean?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please post your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that you claimed to be working.

Comment: @TJ In this case seeing the fiddle helps - we can see that the OP has left the default option of wrapping in onload turned on.  I'm guessing the code is running too soon within his application, while it works on jsfiddle because of this option.  I feel like this is a dupe, but not found a suitable target yet...

Comment: @TJ I just realized something, when I was gonna post my fiddle in the stackoverflow javascript snippet thing, with the exact same code as I had in the JsFiddle, the JsFiddle was using jQuery 1.12, My application is using 1.11 at this moment, so I'll try updating that and see if it helps.

Comment: @DrCox Maybe it has something to do with the fact that fiddle executes the code onload, and your application might not be doing so..? have you tried wrapping original code in `$(function(){ //code })` ..?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't use `radio` button on both `statusbox` and `valuebox`? I mean, that's the very purpose why they were invented in the first place. [Look here](https://jsfiddle.net/cb7oyzaf/7/), No JS needed.

Comment: @TJ Yes I wrapped it in a function(){ //code }

Comment: @choz I guess I'll just have to go with radiobuttons either way. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Taken from your question, your purpose is to select 1 `statusbox` and 1 `valuebox`. And you want to do it in easy way, I suggest you just need to use radiobuttons. If you insist on doing this using jQuery, please explain more about `not working`.